# FK/IK controls in Rigify control too much

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify, vertex-weights

I have my rig set up, but when I move each part, it controls the wrong section of the character; for example, when I move the FK knee of my left leg, it will warp everything around it, actually moving my right leg more than the left. I'm new to this, so I have no idea what might be causing this, but I have a hunch that it's weights. My model was created as one large mesh from a single plane, so it's a single object, and I parented it using Automatic Weights. Any help is appreciated.

BLEND FILE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygop2n4h6ba8uem/frogman.blend?dl=0

Comment: Can you add a blend file and images of the problem to your question? As it stands it sounds like you have weights from the left leg bones on your right legs.

Comment: @Sazerac just added a blend file.